# WSO2IS - Admin Forced Password Reset also sending Locked Account email

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We use the following feature in WSO2IS 5.3.0

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Forced+Password+Reset#ForcedPasswordReset-PasswordResetviaRecoveryEmail

This feature sends an email for the user to reset their password, but also sends the user a "Locked Account" email. Is there a way to prevent the "Locked Account" email being sent ***without*** modifying the source code of the WSO2 extension that seems to be driving this feature? (in particular, the offending line seems to be here https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/recovery/handler/AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler.java#L129 . )

Comment: What do you mean by  "Locked Account" email ? Are you getting two emails ?

Comment: That's correct, we are receiving two emails. One is the correct email (the template name for that one is "AdminForcedPasswordReset"), and one is because the code is locking the account (the template name for that one is "AccountLock"). We would like to avoid sending the "AccountLock" email)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this feature in both Identity Server version 5.3.0 and 5.5.0. Forced password reset via recovery mail put user account to lock state but it does not send two emails for forced password reset and account lock. Please check your steps.

1. Find **Forced Password Reset** claim from wso2 claim dialect (http://wso2.org/claims)
2. Check Supported by Default on http://wso2.org/claims/identity/adminForcedPasswordReset
3. Go to user profile, you will find an attribute name Force Password Reset, make it true by typing "true" in text box.

End of third step you should get only single email regarding Admin password rest.

Comment: Can you verify that you've got "account.lock.handler.notification.manageInternally" set to true during your test? I'm guessing this code is being triggered https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/handler/event/account/lock/AccountLockHandler.java#L490

Comment: Following your steps does send only one email, so that's good. However, setting the claim (and only that claim) via UserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues is producing the two emails.

Comment: This is not the appropriate way. If you need to do this via API call use "UserProfileMgtService" [1]. [1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Forced+Password+Reset#ForcedPasswordReset-PasswordResetviaRecoveryEmail

Comment: I've reworked our code to use UserProfileMgtService but I am still receiving two emails. Is that the way the Admin UI is doing this?

Comment: I retested typing "true" for the "Force Password Reset" claim in the WSO2 Admin UI, and that sent me two emails (when I tested earlier it only got one, that was because the user was already locked). So it seems like I need to modify the code I mention in my original question (which is an acceptable but not ideal solution)